# Language of strings of lengths that are prime is regular? Is C^* regular?

Tags: automata, nondeterminism

With $\Sigma = \{a\}$ I want to see if a language $C = \{a^p \ | \ p \ \text{is prime}\}$ is regular and whether or not $C^*$ is regular.

How would I go about showing whether $C$ or $C^*$ are regular? I know I can construct a DFA/NFA to accept them but I am very confused about the fact that there are an infinite number of primes.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried any of the techniques found in our reference questions, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/755?  We discourage questions that just copy the statement of an exercise and ask us to solve it for you, but if you've made an attempt to self-study this area and apply standard techniques, then editing the question to include that information will help you obtain better answers.

Comment: Also, searching on `regular unary` on this site immediately finds relevant questions: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10555/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/21765/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16293/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4984/755.  We expect you to make a significant effort to search for answers before asking; the search bar in upper-right is helpful for this.