# Operations making non-context-free languages regular

Tags: automata

1. If $A$ is a non-context free language, is $A^*$ a regular language?
2. If $A$ is a non-context free language and $B$ is a regular language, is it possible that their concatenation is a regular language?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be $\{a^p\mid p\text{ is prime}\}$. Let $B$ be $\{a\}^*$.

Both $A^*$ and $A\circ B$ are regular. $A^*$ is $\epsilon+aaa^*$ and  $A\circ B$ is $aaa^*$.

Comment: True, but it's still regular. I'll fix it.

Comment: Note that, if $A$ is a unary language (i.e., uses only a single letter alphabet) as in this case, then in fact the star $A^*$ is always regular. See this question: [Show that the Kleene star of any unary language is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10555/4287). It seems the same holds for $A \cdot \{a\}^*$, because that language consists of all strings longer than the shortest in $A$.